# Finding the max number of a column in MATLAB, which allocates to a specific string

Tags: matlab

Consider that I have a table of such type in MATLAB:

```
Location     String      Number

1              a           26 
1              b           361  
2              c           28
2              a           45 
3              a           78
4              b           82
```

I would like to create a script which returns only 3 rows, which would include the largest Number for each string. So in this case the table returned would be the following:

```
Location    String     Number

3            a         78
1            b         361   
2            c         28
```

The actual table that I want to tackle is much greater, though I wrote this like that for simplicity. How can this task be tackled?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `splitapply`, with an `id` for each row.
Please see the comments for details...

```
% Assign unique ID to each row
tbl.id = (1:size(tbl,1))';
% Get groups of the different strings
g = findgroups(tbl.String);
% create function which gets id of max within each group 
% f must take arguments corresponding to each splitapply table column
f = @(num,id) id(find(num == max(num), 1));
% Use splitapply to apply the function f to all different groups
idx = splitapply( f, tbl(:,{'Number','id'}), g );
% Collect rows
outTbl = tbl(idx, {'Location', 'String', 'Number'});

>> outTbl = 
   Location   String    Number
      3        'a'        78   
      1        'b'       361   
      2        'c'        28
```

Or just a simple loop. This loop is only over the unique values of `String` so should be pretty quick.

```
u = unique(tbl.String);
c = cell(numel(u), size(tbl,2));
for ii = 1:numel(u)
    temp = tbl(strcmp(tbl.String, u{ii}),:);
    [~, idx] = max(temp.Number);
    c(ii,:) = table2cell(temp(idx,:));
end
outTbl = cell2table(c, 'VariableNames', tbl.Properties.VariableNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding max values of each string my idea is.

Create a vector of all your strings and include them only one time. Something like:

`strs=['a','b','c'];`

Then create a vector that will store maximum value of each string:

```
n=length(strs);
max_values=zeros(1,n);
```

Now create a loop with the size of the whole data to compare current max_value with the current value and substitute if `current_value>max_value`:

```
for i=1:your_table_size
   m=find(strs==current_table_string);   % This finds the index of max_values
   if max_values(m)<current_table_Number   % This the the i_th row table_number
      max_values(m)=current_table_Number;
   end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't output what the OP asked for, i.e. a table of all the max rows for each category. Instead it just outputs a vector of all the max values for each category.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Wolfie. I was mostly **pointing the idea** of finding the required and as you saw I did not write the whole script. Thus, yes you are right but replacing the code with the table parameters I believe is not a hard task for OP as long as he gets the idea.